# Vue.js application in an IFRAME, how to reach parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an SPA Vue.js app based on the `webpack` template from vuejs-templates and with single-file components.

For legacy reasons, I have to embed this app in a `IFRAME` in a web page of an existing web site.

From a method within a Vue.js component, I would like to be able to reach the parent window (i.e. the one where the `IFRAME` is declared), for e.g. opening an alert or setting the value of a DOM Element.

I've tried several classic JavaScript/HTML methods but without success.

Comment: You must think about cross-domain issues.

Comment: @jacky Could you please elaborate? Pages are actually in the same domain. Do you have an idea how to achieve that (calling the IFRAME parent) from a component's method? Thx

Comment: just use window.parent.document.getElementById() ... etc.

Comment: @jacky `window.parent.document.getElementById()` works, thanks. Could you write an answer with the same content as your comment, I'll would happily accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the iframe, you can access the parent window object via 'window.parent'  , such as window.parent.document.getElementById.